# Is there a way to preserve Subject emit order when subscribing on the same Scheduler?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have roughly the following setup

```kotlin
enum class Event { Running, Idle, Error }

fun main() {
  val events = PublishSubject.create<Event>().toSerialized()
  val results = PublishSubject.create<Event>().toSerialized()

  // stream1
  events
    .filter { it == Event.Running || it == Event.Idle }
    .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
    .subscribe(results)

  // stream2
  events
    .filter { it == Event.Error }
    .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
    .subscribe(results)

  val observer = results.subscribeWith(TestObserver())

  events.onNext(Event.Running)
  events.onNext(Event.Error)
  events.onNext(Event.Idle)

  observer.awaitValues(3)
  // Almost always fails, because the order is: Running, Idle, Error
  check(observer.values() == listOf(Event.Running, Event.Error, Event.Idle))
}
```

Two questions:

1. Why does this happen? I would expect that emit order is preserved, especially when watching on the shared single-thread backed `Scheduler`
2. Can I somehow "merge" `stream1` and `stream2` so that the order in which they're written to will be retained in this merge point (be it a `Consumer` or `Observable.merge(stream1, stream2)` or whatever else.

Comment: 1) observeOn coalesces work thus you can get multiple values without interleaving. 2) There is an [orderedMerge](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#flowablesorderedmerge) operator but you'll have to tag events with a running index for total order.

Comment: Thank you! I will investigate orderedMerge!